# How can I findViewById() in react-native android

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I'm referring to this in my index.android.js file..

```
<View>
  <CustomView>
    ...
  </CustomView>
</View>
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by `React.findNodeHandle`.

In your case,

```js
...

var { findNodeHandle } = React;

...

render: function() {
  return (
    <View>
      <CustomView ref="customView">
        ...
      </CustomView>
    </View>
  );
},

somethingLikeComponentDidMount: function() {
  var customViewNativeID = findNodeHandle(this.refs.customView);
  // Something else...
}

...
```

might do the work.

For a working example (natively binding two components), check out [here](https://github.com/Neson/react-native-android-design-support/blob/405cc3832b57c162e18a486fcbd7384b2476cbab/lib/TabLayoutAndroid.js#L27) as the JS part and [here](https://github.com/Neson/react-native-android-design-support/blob/405cc3832b57c162e18a486fcbd7384b2476cbab/android/src/main/java/com/reactnativeandroiddesignsupport/views/tab/ReactTabLayoutManager.java#L77-L78) as the native Java part.

Comment: this code doesn't work for me.  I get the error "TypeError: _react.default.findNodeHandle is not a function"

Answer (score 0):

do use refs for the component which can act as the reference for the component

ex:

```
<View>
<TextInput style={styles.textInput}
           ref={'usrname'}
           placeholder={'Username'}
           placeholderTextColor={'red'}
           onChangeText={(userName) => this.setState({userName})}
           value={this.state.userName} />
<TouchableOpacity onPress={this._onPressButton}>
              <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
                <Text> Submit </Text>
              </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
</View>
```

and onPress:

```
_onPressButton: function(e){
    var x = this.state.userName;
    alert(x); //we can also use alert(this.state.userName)
  },
```

Comment: thanks... @Pramod Mg but how can i use it in my java code? Can i pass it to my module? Like Mymodule._module.func(x);

Comment: Cause I want to use my CustomView in my java like..
View canvasView  = findViewById(R.id.CustomView);
Soo that I can capture what ever inside my CustomView, the problem is react-native does not have an xml, i knew its very easy if it has an xml file i can just say.. findViewById()...