# ReactNative: Get element by findViewById inside NativeBridge code

Tags: java, react-native

Is possible to get element from React Native view through native Java code?

For example this is part of my code in `app.js`:

```
<View style={styles.imageContainer}>
   <Image id="bitmapPreview"/>
</View>
```

and my Native Bridge code:

```
iv = (ImageView) context.getCurrentActivity().findViewById(R.id.bitmapPreview);
```

I couldn't find answer for that :(

Comment: You can use [getIdentifier()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources#getIdentifier(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) android method to get imageId on drawable.
You can check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15488238/using-android-getidentifier

Comment: Ok, now I have:
iv = (ImageView) context.getCurrentActivity().getResources().getIdentifier("bitmapPreview", "drawable", context.getPackageName());

Isn't work. I've got:
error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to ImageView

Comment: getIdentifier() return int type, which is an ID of image.
You should write:
int imageId = context.getCurrentActivity().getResources().getIdentifier("bitmapPreview", "drawable", context.getPackageName());
 iv = (ImageView) context.getCurrentActivity().findViewById(imageId);
(I not tested yet)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34558664/7841495
Probably that resolve my problems :D